# Why can't I log into my old account?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

[image]
It says my code has expired. Can I renew it? It's been a while seinse I played but I liked the game and want to play again but I would not like to start again

Answer (score -2):

Try messaging the devs. They might know if there is a way to fix it. If I had to guess, I think it might be because they had a problem with bots. If you message them they might be able to fix it. Also, look up Error Code 137 for the game.

Comment: You need to actually provide a solution, not just present basic troubleshooting tips.